# Get first two items positionally from Import-CSV row

Tags: powershell

I have a series of files that have changed some header naming and column counts over time. However, the files always have the first column as the start date and second column as the end date.

I would like to get just these two columns, but the name has changed over time.
What I have tried is this:

```
 $FileContents=Import-CSV -Path "$InputFilePath" 
 foreach ($line in $FileContents)
 {
     $StartDate=$line[0]
     $EndDate=$line[1]
 }
```

...but $FileContents is (I believe) an array of a type (objects?) that I'm not sure how to positionally access in PowerShell. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The files switched from comma delimiter to pipe delimiter a while back and there are 1000s of files to work with, so I use Import-CSV because it can implicitly read either format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$FileContents=get-content -Path "$InputFilePath" 

for ($i=0;$i -lt $FileContents.count;$i++){
    $textrow = ($FileContents[$i]).split(",")
    $StartDate=$textrow[0]
    $EndDate=$textrow[1]

    #do what you want with the variables
    write-host $startdate
    write-host $EndDate
}
```

pending you are referencing a csv file....

Comment: An assumption with this approach is that the delimiter is in the data otherwise there will be issues with the split and with extra quotes. You also need to skip your first row, so `$i=0` -> `$i=1` otherwise the old header will be a object in your data.

Comment: This worked. I did "StartDateColumn","EndDateColumn" as the headers with a "foreach ($line in $FileContents)". Using $line.StartDateColumn got the result needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `-Header` parameter to give the first to columns of the csv the header names you want. Then you'll skip the first line that has the old header.

```
$FileContents = Import-CSV -Path "$InputFilePath" -Header "StartDate","EndDate" | Select-Object "StartDate","EndDate" -Skip 1

foreach ($line in $FileContents) {
    $StartDate = $line.StartDate
    $EndDate = $line.EndDate
}
```

Here's an example:

```
Example.csv

a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6

Import-CSV -Path Example.csv -Header "StartDate","EndDate" | Select-Object "StartDate","EndDate" -Skip 1

StartDate EndDate
--------- -------
1         2
4         5
```

Comment: I like your answer more then mine, hence I upvoted it. `Header` parameter is also available for `Convertfrom-Csv`. *thumbs up*

Comment: GJ, but not necessary 'Select-Object "StartDate","EndDate" -Skip 1', because 'Select -skip 1' is enought

Answer (score 3):

If you use `Import-Csv`, PowerShell will indeed create an object for you. The "columns" are calles *properties*. You can select properties with `Select-Object`. You have to name the properties, you want to select. Since you don't know the property names in advance, you can get the names with `Get-Member`. The first two properties should match the first two columns in your CSV.

Use the following sample code and apply it to your script:

```
$csv = @'
1,2,3,4,5
a,b,c,d,e
g,h,i,j,k
'@

$csv = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
$properties = $csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -First 2 -ExpandProperty Name
$csv | Select-Object -Property $properties
```

Comment: You should show how to get the value in the loop. e.g. `foreach ($line in $csv) {$startdate = $line.($properties[0])}`

Answer (score 0):

Other solution with foreach (%=alias of foreach) and split :

```
Get-Content "example.csv" | select -skip 1 | %{$row=$_ -split ',', 3; [pscustomobject]@{NewCol1=$row[0];NewCol2=$row[1]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build predicate into the select too like this :

```
Get-Content "example.csv" | select @{N="Newcol1";E={($_ -split ',', 3)[0]}}, @{N="Newcol2";E={($_ -split ',', 3)[1]}} -skip 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With convertfrom-string

```
Get-Content "example.csv" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Header col1, col2 | select -skip 1
```